# AVCaptureSession with videoDataOuput and stillImageOutput

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, camera, avfoundation

I'm writing an application where I'm using AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to get the sample buffers, do some dots detection and display it in real time.

The user also has the capability to capture the image.

The problem is that, because I'm using the same session, the image quality for capturing still images is the same as the one for the video.

I'm using captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: delegate method to capture the frames and captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: to capture the still images

I'm wondering if there is a way to capture the frames in AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium and when capturing the image, switch to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the session's `sessionPreset` property while the session is running.

Change it to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` before capturing the image and then back to `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` in the completion block of `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:`.

Beware that changing the preset will blank the camera briefly while it changes over so it may be difficult to capture a picture of a specific frame instantly, but there is never really any guarantee as `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`'s `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:` gets done when it gets done. :)